# Java Scanner object in constructor?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the below inside of a class and it's returning an error.

My teacher had told me I can create an instance variable out of the scanner object if I instantiate it in the constructor and import the java.util.Scanner package.

Why won't the below work?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Javaio {
    private char scanner;

    public Javaio() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Comment: `private Scanner scanner`

Answer (score 2):

A `Scanner` is not a `char`.  Change the datatype of `scanner` to match:

```
private Scanner scanner;
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is a class..
you seem to have misunderstood the concept a little( or probably tired of it)

simple declare a new object of the Scanner class..

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
```